# Improve performance of R code for random sampling

Tags: r, performance, out-of-memory, random

I am trying to generate confidence intervals for a dataset by simulating the distribution in R with random sampling. However the way I am doing this results in R running out of memory. I am not very experienced with R and would appreciate knowning whether there is a way I could optimise this to run well in R, or if another language like python would be better for this (I only know some R and python). The code is below.

When I run this I get the error 'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 359.9 Mb'.

Would it be a lot more efficient if instead of using `sapply()` I ran the simulations sequentially in a for loop for k= 1:9000, so that R doesn't have to store all the simulations in it's memory until they are all completed?

Thanks in advance

```
#import probability distribution: 
ps <-read.table("Asianpig_probability_distribution.txt", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

#what ps looks like:
ps

0.1     0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5       0.6       0.7       0.8      0.9   1.0
1 0.5399651 0.24848 0.1235064 0.0553278 0.0226341 0.0075721 0.0020886 0.0003944 2.94e-05 2e-06
n <- 1e4

set.seed(42)

#run the simulations 
sims <- sapply(1:9000, 
function(k) 
rowSums(
replicate(k, sample(x=(1:10)/10, size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=ps))) / k)

#Then calculate quantile range on output of simulations:
quants <- apply(sims, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
```

Encase context helps readability the code is simulating the mean score of genes with between 1 to 9000 SNPs. Each SNP is randomly assigned a score betweeon 0-1 based on a probability distribution (ps). This is done n times for genes of every size between 1 to 9000 SNPs. 
Then I calculate the quantiles for each of these size categories.

Comment: One easy performance improvement: Don't draw new samples for each number of SNPs. Draw 9000 samples and use the first for 1 SNP, the first two for two SNPs, ... Then you should try if you would run out of memory if you only calculate for k == 9000. If that's the case, you'd need to do that step in chunks (of `n`
). And of course, if you can choose the quantiles of interest a-priori, you don't need to store the simulated values, but could calculate the quantiles in the loop and store those.

Comment: thanks that's a good suggestion. I will try that